# How to change the styling on every page?

Tags: css, home-page-component

I am trying to override the css of the home page and other standard pages. And below is the approach I am following, but seems like I am missing something. **Could someone help on this?**
***Approach:***
1. Create a home page component on the left side bar
2. Add the following code to it:

```
<style>
 { background-color:black !important; 
   background-image:none!important; 
   color:green!important; font-style: bold!important; 
   border:none !important; }
</style>
```

3.  Attach the home page component to the home page layout.
4. Assign the layout.

For some odd reason this is not working for me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you make sure the show html was checked when you pasted this code in the homepage component

Comment: Yep, it was checked.

Comment: arent you missing the css selector to which you want to apply the css style like body {background-color:black !important; 
   background-image:none!important; }. personally wouldnt recommend to hack the SFDC css, it can get broken by every release

Comment: 1 up for the comment. and 1 down for my question! Thanks @Seb_Wagner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to mess around with css, this is all you need to do

copy paste this code in your sidebar component :

```
<style>#bodyCell{background-color:black !important;  background-image:none!important; color:green!important; font-style: bold!important;     border:none !important;}</style>
```

Based on what area you want to make this style sheet applicable you can select the ID, class here I took the inner tables Id="bodyCell"

how did I get the Id: Go to chrome right click inspect element. Trace over the tree and hit the table / the div in the tree and choose the Id and override the css

[image]

Comment: How would it work on pages where there is no sidebar? Is there any work arounds for that?

Comment: Nope, the basic requirement for this trick to work is that you need to have sidebar enabled.Are you speaking about standard pages that do not have sidebar/ visualforce pages?

Comment: Beware that this might look neat for the home page but when you traverse through objects you may see the background being applied across the page/ part of the page. You will have to tweak the CSS to be specific to homepage and not traverse across the objects.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the standard pages like Dashboard or Chatter!

Comment: Inspect dashboard components top div and apply the css to the div class / ID as specified by inspect element method.